# Software implementation of I2C bus via port expander

Tags: arduino, esp8266, i2c

There is:

- Arduino or Esp8266
- 8 port expanders MCP23017
- 8 HTU21D humidity sensors with I2C interface.

Port expanders have the ability to change the address on the I2C bus using jumpers A0-A2. Humidity sensors do not have such functionality, they have the same address. Is it possible to connect humidity sensors with I2C interface to the port expander via GPIO and programmatically implement the I2C bus.

**From the microcontroller, I need to access the humidity sensor data through the port expander. How to implement this?**

The theoretical scheme of such a connection
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think to solve this problem as follows:
I put all humidity sensors on one I2C bus, but I will supply power to them from the pin from the port expander. As a result, to collect information I will refer to one I2C address but before that switch the power to the sensors through the port expander, only one sensor will be turned on at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend using the I2C GPIO port expander to implement the i2c protocol for below reasons:

1. First, since the port expander is already operating on i2c frequency, the I2C protocol via bit-banging the GPIO pins of the port expander will be slower or there might be unforeseen timing issues.
2. Implementing the i2c protocol might turn out to be a little tricky/risky. For instance, you might need to implement the clock-stretching feature in your software i2c.

I would recommend using the i2c bus switch http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tca9545a.pdf which is a lot simple to use and multiplexes a single i2c bus between 4 i2c devices and the devices can have the same or different i2c slave addresses. The switch itself has a configurable i2c address (so multiple of them can be used). The required channel can be enabled by sending i2c data to the switch address. Then the subsequent i2c communication with the desired device will happen via the enabled channel.